# How to convert string into object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a string that looks like this:

`'a=aaa,bbb,ccc&b=aaa,bbb,ccc&c=aaa,bbb,ccc'`

and I want to change it into an object that looks like this:

`{ a: 'aaa, bbb, ccc', b: 'aaa, bbb, ccc', c: 'aaa, bbb, ccc' }`

I've tried splitting on the `&` and then `=` but that results in:

`[ ['a', 'aaa','bbb','ccc'], ['b', 'aaa','bbb','ccc'], ['c', 'aaa','bbb','ccc' ] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a package like [QS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) or [URLSearchParams Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) to support any browsers like IE and Node.js as well.

See example below:

```js
console.log(Qs.parse('a=aaa,bbb,ccc&b=aaa,bbb,ccc&c=aaa,bbb,ccc'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/qs@6.7.0/dist/qs.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using QS but I still get `ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined` Any ideas to get it to work?

Comment: Looking at QS's code it does not refer to `URLSearchParams` so it must be coming from another code. QS does its own parsing.

Answer (score 7):

You could just use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams('a=aaa,bbb,ccc&b=aaa,bbb,ccc&c=aaa,bbb,ccc');
var obj = Object.fromEntries(params.entries())
console.log(obj);
```

If your browser doesn't have either of those functions, you can use a polyfill:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill
https://github.com/feross/fromentries

Comment: That looks great but I'm getting `ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined` when I try to run it in my code which is an Ember fastboot environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just use `split()`, you need to make the object out of the split keys and values. You can do this in a `reduce` loop (or a `forEach()`):

```js
s = 'a=aaa,bbb,ccc&b=aaa,bbb,ccc&c=aaa,bbb,ccc'
let pairs = s.split('&')                // each pair is like a=aaa,bbb,ccc
let obj = pairs.reduce((obj,data)=> {
    let [k, v] = data.split('=')        // split each pair into key/value
    obj[k] = v                          // add the key to the object
    return obj
}, {})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate thru the resulting array like this-

```
var myObj = {};
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
        var newProp = arr[i].shift();     
        myObj[newProp] =  arr[i].join()
    }
}
```

Didn't test it but I think that would work.

Comment: I don't think this will work on a string, will probably have to use split on the string first.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the string into an array of `[key, value]` entries by first splitting on the `&`, then mapping over the split output to split once again by `=`  and then use `Object.fromEntries`.

```
kv_str = 'a=aaa,bbb,ccc&b=aaa,bbb,ccc&c=aaa,bbb,ccc'
kv_pairs = kv_str.split('&') 
kv_entries = kv_pairs.map(kv => kv.split('='))
kv_obj = Object.fromEntries(kv_entries)
// kv_obj will be: {a: 'aaa,bbb,ccc', b: 'aaa,bbb,ccc', c: 'aaa,bbb,ccc'}
```